# Storage data in internal storage Android

Tags: android

I am developing some android application for a couple weeks. It is good to save serializable data in internal storage (interface Serializable) or it is better to save it in local database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything depends on your requirement and data which you are going to show in your application.

There are 5 ways to data storage in Android:

1) shared preferences
   2) internal files
   3) external files
   4) sqllite
   5) network storage in the cloud.

**1) SHARED PREFERENCES** are internal to the application and device. This data is not available to other applications. User can not directly manipulate this data by mounting on to a USB port. This data is removed automatically when the application is removed.

**2) INTERNAL FILES** is very similar to shared preferences except that these are standalone files that you can write to with out any predefined structure. Shared preferences is structured key/value pair data and follows a few other semantics imposed by Android for using them as preferences. I suppose I could easily switch to internal files from shared preferences as they are pretty close. Importantly I haven't found a "compelling" or "impending" reason to switch with urgency.

**3) EXTERNAL FILES** are stored on the sdcard. These become public files that other apps including the user could see outside the context of your application.

**4) SQLite** For subsquent releases this is an excellent option as I can be much faster and use much less power. This is the ideal state ,but if the app becomes really popular we will take this step. However one must code so that this switch can happen with minimal change to the rest of the application. One way to do this is to have an explicit service layer that separates persistence aspects completely outside of the logic. These databases also are private to the application and not available to the outside apps.

**5) NETWORK STORAGE** is not an option at all as I need the app to work when disconnected. There may be supplemental opportunities to use parse.com or a similar BAAS (Back-end as a service) platform to do some of that.

Answer (score 0):

Better to save in Local database. It depends on what are are you storing.

Comment: Use  SQLite Database.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your data and how do you want to show the data.

If the data needs massage or volume is relatively big, It is better to save in local database. And you will also have other benefits like SQL query, filter, and better performance in ListView.

Otherwise, you can save it as file or SystemSharedPreference.